# Passing linked list from C to C++

Tags: c++, c, qt

Are there known issues with passing linked lists from C code to C++? 
I have a Qt dialogue that I'm adding to legacy C code. A Qt class (in a C++ library) calls a C library function, which returns a static pointer to a linked list. That list is created in the C library. For example:

C code:

```
typedef my_struct_s my_struct_t, *my_struct_p;
struct { 
  int some_data;
  double some_more_data;
  my_struct_p next;
} my_struct_s;
void create_list()
{
  my_struct_p next;
  SP_head = (my_struct_p) calloc(1, sizeof(my_struct_t));
  next = (my_struct_p) calloc(1, sizeof(my_struct_t));
  SP_head->some_data = 1;
  next->some_data = 2;
  SP_head->next = next;
}
static my_struct_p SP_head=(my_struct_p)0;

extern my_struct_p get_list() {
  if(!SP_head)
     create_list();
  return SP_head;
}
```

C++ code:

```
myclass::do_something()
{
    my_struct_p list = get_list();
    for(my_struct_p ptr = list; ptr; ptr = ptr->next)
    {
         std::cout << ptr->value;
    }
}
```

`SP_head` is valid and contains a bunch of entries when I obtain it. In my debugger I can see the next entries are populated and valid on return from the function `get_list()`.

When I try to assign `ptr=ptr->next`, whether inside a for loop or at the end of a while loop or via a temporary pointer, the value is `null`. i.e

```
temp_ptr = ptr->next;  
// temp_ptr is null
// but I can see ptr->next looks ok in a debugger
```

I've now changed the code to copy each element of the list into an array and return that array, and it works fine. Is this something to do with the stack and an incompatibility with C and C++, or just an indication that I have a memory problem somewhere else?

Comment: Seeing `my_struct` would likely be helpful, along the other typedefs. Further, your code appears incorrect (`get_head()` should be returning a `my_struct_p`, not a `my_struct`) indicating this may not be the *real* code, thereby further making an accurate answer more difficult. A [SSCCE](http://www.sscce.org) would be *very* helpful, and you may find your problem without any help while writing it. Finally, are you compiling debug-no-optimizations? Never trust a debugger on release code unless you're prepared to step into asm.

Comment: i don't see how seeing my_struct would help. it's just a plain old structure with a next pointer. The above is just pseudocode and yes the function should return a my_struct_p. Of course I am compiling my debug mode with no optimizations. The question is whether or not there is a known issue with the concept of doing the above. If not, then I know I need to look for a bug earlier on.

Comment: edited to show example struct and useage

Comment: There shouldn't be anything odd here, save for potentially different packing/alignment. I'd also say caling conv, but you've probably already checked it. Assuming those are all the same compiling C or C++ code this should work. I'm curious to know if the chance happens by you whether your experience changes if you move the `next` pointer to the *top* of the structure. I know it sounds odd, and perhaps you've already done it, but still, its an interesting problem. You may be right regarding a problem somewhere else.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Of course, C++ is prepared to handle C, then you should assume that there are *no* incompatibility when the *proper* interface is used.

After all, there are many SW out there implemented in C and interfaced from C++. I'm using, for instance, [SWI-Prolog](http://www.swi-prolog.org/) - implemented in C - from Qt.

But to compile your code, I had to do several changes: here the bottom line

file my_list.h

```
#ifdef __cplusplus 
extern "C" {
#endif

struct my_struct_s {
  int some_data;
  double some_more_data;
  struct my_struct_s *next;
};
typedef struct my_struct_s my_struct_t, *my_struct_p;

void create_list();
extern my_struct_p get_list();

#ifdef __cplusplus 
}
#endif
```

file my_list.c

```
#include "my_list.h"
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

static my_struct_p SP_head=(my_struct_p)0;

void create_list()
{
  my_struct_p next;
  SP_head = (my_struct_p) calloc(1, sizeof(my_struct_t));
  next = (my_struct_p) calloc(1, sizeof(my_struct_t));
  SP_head->some_data = 1;
  next->some_data = 2;
  SP_head->next = next;
}

my_struct_p get_list() { return SP_head; }
```

file main.cpp

```
#include "my_list.h"
#include <iostream>

class myclass {
public:
    void do_something()
    {
        my_struct_p list = get_list();
        for(my_struct_p ptr = list; ptr; ptr = ptr->next)
         std::cout << ptr->some_data << std::endl;
    }
};

int main() {
    create_list();
    myclass c;
    c.do_something();
}
```

now that compile and run:

```
g++ my_list.c main.cpp
./a.out
1
2
```